# How to "Clear Format" in Google Sheets via Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting

In my Google Sheet, I currently remove formatting by manually going to `Format > Clear Formatting`.

How can I programmatically (via Apps Script) clear any/all formatting that may exist in a Google Sheet's row(s) and/or column(s)?

Clarification: I am aware of the [Text Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text) that has formatting functions (eg. setForegroundColor(), setItalic(), setTextAlignment(), etc), but I'm not aware of any single function that will do the same thing as the `Format > Clear Formatting` function that is available in the Main Menu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a clearFormats() method in the Sheet Class.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clearformats

Example from the docs:

```
// This example assumes there is a sheet named "first"
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var first = ss.getSheetByName("first");
 first.clearFormats();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `clearFormat()` function I am looking for is in the `Range Class`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function clearFormatting() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  activeSheet.clear({
    formatOnly: true,
    contentsOnly: false
  });
}
```