# Import xlsx in normal paste and get all rows and columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, xlsx

I created a script that can import xlsx file to google sheet and its currently working but I need to modify it to get the whole sheet without using specific range and paste it as normal text since the current output text has bold and large fonts, Can someone help me what I need to modify or change to my script?

My script

```
 const sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange("B1:V5231").getValues();
 const target = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getSheetByName('sheetname');
 target.getRange(target.getLastRow()+1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceValues);
```

Thank you!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `I created a script that can import xlsx file to google sheet and its currently working but I need to modify it to get the whole sheet without using specific range and paste it as normal text since the current output text has bold and large fonts` and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Just to confirm, the sourceSheet in this would be the xlsx? It would be nice to have the full code sample, I built one using the same idea, however both were normal Sheet file and it copy the data normally, maybe some example sheet and xlsx file would be great.

Comment: @rodskies For clarification, when you said _"**I need to modify it to get the whole sheet without using specific range**"_, do you mean you'd like to change this part `sourceSheet.getRange("B1:V5231")` on your sample script to something that will still get all of the values from your google sheet that has the **.xlsx** file data without specifying a range?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, my script right now can only get data in static data range, I need to modify it to non static or getting data without using specific range like (B1:V5231) in spreadsheet, also I have issue with the imported data in spreadsheet it has large and bold fonts and normal fonts my plan is to make it paste as normal text.

Comment: @IrvinJayG. Yes, correct.

Comment: @rodskies Since you want to make this line of your code `const sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange("B1:V5231").getValues();` to be dynamic. Have you tried using the **[getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)** instead of using the **getRange()**?

Comment: Hi @IrvinJayG. , It work's thank you for the input, next issue to resolve is normal paste of the data when imported to spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that the discussions have already been advanced and an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing discussions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SUGGESTION

If I have understood your question clearly, you want to dynamically get the range on your sheet that contains `.xlsx` data instead of explicitly using a specific range using the `getRange()` method.

You may try using the `getDataRange()` method as it returns a range corresponding to the dimensions in which data is present on your sheet.

As for the **normal pasting of data as text without formatting**, you can try using `getDisplayValues()` instead of using the `getValues()` as this will return the values as `String` objects.

*[UPDATE]*

If `getDisplayValues()` doesn't remove the text formatting, you can also use the `clearFormats` method as per this [existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37010635/15384825). This method will clear the contents and/or format. See this sample usage below:

### Script

```
const sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange("B1:V5231").getValues();
const target = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getSheetByName('sheetname');
target.getRange(target.getLastRow() + 1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceValues);
target.clearFormats();
```

> The `clearFormats` method will remove the formatting of the text on the **target** sheet after setting the values.

### References:

- [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) Method
- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) Method
- [clearFormats()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clear) Method

Comment: @rodskies Please try the updated suggestions above and see if any of them work for you.